# are global variables available in the inserted event handler of the objectdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

this doesn't work

```
protected void ods_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{

    if (@Session["PaginaAnterior"] == @"http://www.francawdesign.com.br/veiculos/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx") 
        Response.Redirect("~/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx");
}
```

this on the other hand works

```
protected void ods_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{

    if (@"http://www.francawdesign.com.br/veiculos/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx" == @"http://www.francawdesign.com.br/veiculos/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx") 
        Response.Redirect("~/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx");
}
```

this also doesn't work myGlobalVariable has the same values as the string it compares

```
protected void ods_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (@myGlobalVariable == @"http://www.francawdesign.com.br/veiculos/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx") 
        Response.Redirect("~/paginas/anunciar/carro/identificacao.aspx");
}
```

since a long time I have this doubt. My guess is that this features are not available at the time of this event. Is that correct?

Comment: Saying "this doesn't work", doesn't work.

Comment: And what do you think `@myGlobalVariable` means?

Comment: when I do a comparison in the inserted event handler of the objectdatasource the only thing that works is the comparison of two static strings defined in the event handler anything else :   values stored in session, global variables and etc "doesn't work"

Comment: @myGlobalVariable is a global variable with a value the same as the static string it is compared to. the at sign is to encode \

Comment: Again, what do you mean, "the comparison doesn't work"? Do you mean that the comparison fails when it should succeed? Can you show the definition of these "global variables"

Comment: I m using forward slashes maybe is that the problem?

Comment: The `@` does not mean encoding; maybe not ever, but certainly not in this context. Where did you get that idea? `@"string literal"` means to treat the string literally, or "verbatim". It does not have that meaning in front of a variable.